# Run AWS Beanstalk app only at certain time periods

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I only want the beanstalk app to run during working hours 8 - 5. How do I configure it so that I automatically starts at 8am and shuts down at 5pm on weekdays and turns off completely on weekends?

Comment: see https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/05/aws-elastic-beanstalk-supports-time-based-scaling/

Answer (score 3):

EB only supports time-based scaling of the application server ASG. It does not support time-based scaling for ELB, RDS, or other supporting services:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.as.html#using-features.managing.as.timebased

You'll need to take a hybrid approach to this if you want to shut down your entire infrastructure.

Comment: the application is all i needed to turn off. rds is on-demand so that's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

## Tutorial to shut down auto-scaling (EC2) at night:

> Note: you can use this guide for scaling up and down at times, shutting down and restarting, just change the configuration.

1. Navigate to

   - Elastic Beanstalk
   - Environment
   - Your-environment
   - Configuration
2. Collapse 'instances' or scroll down to 'Capacity'

[image: EBS Capacity]

3. Scroll a little further down to 'Time-based scaling'

[image: Time Based Scaling]

4. Add scheduled action
5. Add one action for shutting down, one for restarting

   - For the recurrence (cron-job): `minutes hours days weeks months`
   - Example, every day 07:00am: `0 7 * * *`
   - Example, every day 07:00pm: `0 19 * * *`
   - Shut down: all capacities to 0
   - Starting: all capacities to your desired value

[image: Example scheduled action]

6. Add a similar action for restarting
7. Make sure your end-date is correctly configured. If you want to be safe, make sure the startup script is running at least one day longer than the shutdown script to make sure you don't end up forgetting why your environment went down forever.